# FormView.UpdateItem(true) works differently in ASP.NET 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, webforms

There is different behavioral found once the target .NET framework of project was changed from 3.5 to 4.0. Page contains FormView, ObjectDataSource and button causes validation.

Example code in button event handler:

```
protected void ButtonUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Page.Validate("AssignValidation");
    if (!Page.IsValid)
        return;

    // Make the form invalid by some update of form field

    FormView1.UpdateItem(true);

    // .NET 3.5 - Page.IsValid == true
    // .NET 4.0 - Page.IsValid == false
}
```

.NET 3.5 - UpdateItem(true) just stores the uptates into database, no (custom) validations are triggered
.NET 4.x - UpdateItem(true) triggers validation, validators correctly validates and no update to db is done

Can it be caused by any improvement/fix in ASP.NET which were done in 4.0 release? Would you help me to understand why it works differently in both versions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Mike the last instance is to check .NET Framework code.
.NET 3.5 UpdateItem()

```
public virtual void UpdateItem(bool causesValidation) {
    HandleUpdate(String.Empty, causesValidation);
}
```

.NET 4.5.1 UpdateItem()

```
public virtual void UpdateItem(bool causesValidation) { 
    ResetModelValidationGroup(causesValidation, String.Empty); 
    HandleUpdate(String.Empty, causesValidation);
} 

private void ResetModelValidationGroup(bool causesValidation, string validationGroup) { 
    _modelValidationGroup = null;
    if (causesValidation && Page != null) { 
        Page.Validate(validationGroup); 
        if (EnableModelValidation) {
            _modelValidationGroup = validationGroup; 
        }
    }
}
```

This explain the different behavioral as in this case the validations are run as expected .NET 4.x. The method ResetModelValidationGroup doesn't exist in .NET 3.5 but was refactored from code in HandleEvent method and called also in UpdateItem method.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 3.5 might not have been triggering validation because the documentation is the same for 3.5 and 4.0 true should trigger validation for both versions.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.formview.updateitem(v=vs.90).aspx

Why validate and then update in your click handler I would reverse the two operations.

Comment: Agree with you that validation should be triggered in both versions. Code change may help to resolve but it will require a lot effort as this is not the only page in the system which uses FormView :) I would like to understand it at first and then decide if code need to be changed and what will be the best way to do it. Thanks

Comment: Easiest solution just set to false to get what you were seeing in 3.5

Comment: Mike, I appreciate your input and agree that what you suggest would help in this particular scenario but it doesn't explain what changed in FormView in those two versions and why it behaves differently

Comment: And the only way to get that answer is to look at the source. Feel free, it's open source

Comment: Actually everything else is because web forms is part of the base classes and not released. So I would file a bug report on connect ( Microsoft  bug report site )